# How to set primary key in strapi other than id?

Tags: mysql, node.js, database, npm, strapi

Strapi seems to be setting **id**  as primary key while creating a model(collection). How can I set another keyword as the primary key, for example `account_number` for Account model(collection).

I am using strapi 3.6.3 and latest mysql as database in the backend.

Answer (score 3):

The ability to customize a primary key is no longer an option (for the time being). It is recommended to use the UUID plugin if you would like an additional unique, non-serial integer key.

https://forum.strapi.io/t/bookshelf-custom-id/719

Comment: The [issue on github](https://github.com/strapi/strapi/issues/1762) was closed for comments and the question/request was moved over to [the feedback website](https://feedback.strapi.io/developer-experience/p/allow-customization-of-primary-key-id-type-and-name) in 2022. Since then (and despite almost 50 upvotes) there has been no further development.

Comment: Yes, unfortunate to see. I suppose no answer is also an answer sometimes! There are good arguments to be made for enforcing this type of data model consistency especially in a solution that aims to simplify relations and API extensibility. It can be frustrating though when you're prevented from implementing your own design choices.